# Whether the brightness change while taking a image, change the object size in a image?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am having the image A(image of one red ball). lets take A1 as the brightness increased view of A. let take A2 as brightness decreased view of A. I need to compare A1 and A2. while I measure its counter, is there possibility in size change of the red ball.

Brighter Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQmPg.jpg
Low Brightness: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE0Fe.jpg

all the objects all same. brightness only changed. when I found its counter, it gives me a different contour area size. I want to show that the images are same.

Comment: Please consider adding a few images, the code you have, better explain what you're trying to achieve, and why your code doesn't work. As is, it's totally unclear what you're asking

Comment: thanks for ur reply. i added images.

Answer (score 0):

Not in and of itself. However, if you use certain levels of a particular colour [or combination of colour] to trigger the detection, then a lighter image will have a lighter red colour, and a ball may well have a varying level of red [if it's an actual photograph of a sphere or an accurately rendered drawing] due to the reflection of the ball, so your code may detect more or less of the ball. The actual size, however, should be the same.

I should add that, if you take an image through a camera lens, and adjust the aperture to make it more or less bright, that will affect the depth of field - in other words, "how far from the focus distance that is sharp". This will affect the apparent size of an object that is out of the perfect focus, because the edges are blurred. This does not apply if the image has been adjusted in a photo manipulating or drawing program to just become lighter or darker.